# Is there a way to nullify SIGSTOP for a certain script?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals, systemd

I have created a script and I want it to be virtually "immune" to SIGSTOP.
I understand that both SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be trapped or ignored.
I know that the init system for Linux cannot receive a "fatal" signal due to it having the SIGNAL_UNKILLABLE flag on its signal struct flags (although the latter half of that sentence flies over my head for the most part).
I'm willing to edit my kernel to grant this script immunity, the only problem is that I don't know how.
So, my question is, is there a way to nullify SIGSTOP for a certain script/process?

I was able to deal with SIGKILL thanks to the Restart parameter in the service file for my script (using systemd), and while I have scrolled through the manuals looking for something similar for suspended processes, I haven't found anything yet.

Is there anything similar to Restart=always for process suspension caused by SIGSTOP?

I would rather not have to go through the process of changing things in or related to the kernel, but if it's the only way I will.

Thanks.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to nullify these signals? Why/who is sending these signals?

Comment: @kaylum I need to nullify SIGCONT because I don't want to be able to use it against my script.  I am sending these signals, and I am sending them because I will try to disable the script, but I want my script to be immune so I am unable to.

Comment: But why? Why do you need to protect against yourself? Are you expecting someone else will try to send those signals? The usual way to protect against such things is to use the Linux permissions system. That may not be feasible in your case but it is not clear what the underlying motivation is.

Comment: @kaylum
I'd rather not say, but it's to help kick my porn habit.

Comment: Can you just run it as another user? Assuming you don't have root access.

Comment: Would sudo be considered root access?  I could totally give somebody else the root password.

Comment: Yes, sudo is root access. But you can turn that off for yourself, give the root password to someone else, create a new user just for the app you want to protect and then start the app as that user. Then you won't be able to kill or stop the process from your normal user account.

Comment: I thought about that before, and it does seem to be the best option right now, although it would be an inconvenience for package management and wireless connections..  Any other ideas?  If not, the answer you gave is good enough.  Perhaps there's a better distribution for this?

Comment: Hey Teague, I sincerely appreciate your candidness for why you're wanting a solution to this problem. I don't have a solution just yet, but I'm working on it.

Comment: @Roguebantha That's wonderful to hear!  If you'd like, do keep me posted.  For now, I shall let somebody else set my root password.

Comment: @TeagueFoster Even if you give the root password to someone else you can still configure `sudo` to allow you to run some admin commands like `apt` for package installation. That is, you can whitelist some "safe" commands.

Comment: Hey Teague, there's at least a basic answer that might go about solving the problem you asked. However, to go out of character for a moment, I might recommend that the absolute best way of solving your underlying issue is to find someone who can hold you accountable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the best solution I can come up with is SELinux.

SELinux is a kernel add-on created by the NSA that was later released to the public. It is commonly used on Linux systems and comes by default on Android devices. SELinux allows the creation of "contexts". Contexts are an additional label provided to files and processes that allow the subdivision of responsibility and permissions.

How does this solve your problem? Well, you can limit your SELinux permissions for your user processes (even for the root user) so that you're not even allowed to signal this other process at all. In fact, you can prevent any interaction with it whatsoever. If you'd like, you could go so far as to prevent yourself from even being able to turn SELinux off (although it's probably better that you don't if you can avoid it from an operational perspective). This is at some level probably the closest you'll get to a solution that is anywhere near the range of not-hackable. That being said, SELinux setup and configuration for this purpose is not exactly a walk in the park. Documentation is limited (but exists), distro-specific, and in some cases even esoteric. I do have some experience with SELinux myself.

Edit:
Doing some quick googling, it appears possible to install SELinux on Arch, but like most things on Arch, it requires some effort - more than should fit in a StackOverflow comment block. However I'll briefly describe your set of goals here once SELinux is installed:

- Determine the context that you are currently in. Using the "id" command should provide this context.
- Use a [context process transition](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/How_does_a_process_get_into_a_certain_context) so that when you execute your script, that script runs in a new context. You will probably need to create a new context for your script to run in.
- Create sepolicy rules allowing that script to interact with your processes however you need. Perhaps this includes the ability to kill other processes in a different context, or read from a tcp port using sniffing, etc. etc. You can use the [audit2allow](https://linux.die.net/man/1/audit2allow) program to help you create these rules.

By default, SELinux denies anything it doesn't explicitly allow. Your goal now is to make sure that everything you might want to do on your system is allowed, and add policy rules to allow all those things. Looking at the SELinux audit logs is a great way to see everything SELinux is complaining about - it's your job to go through and convert all those audit failures into "allow" rules.

Once all that is done, just make sure not to "allow" whatever context your processes/shell start in from being able to kill or signal the context that your script runs in, and you should be done. Now trying to SIGSTOP or SIGKILL should generate a "Permission denied error".

Comment: I'll give SELinux a shot!  If you'd like to try and come up with a solution for my current system (Arch [or honestly whatever distro would make this easier for you]), I would be a fool to say no.  So, absolutely!

Comment: I've looked up how to create a new context in SELinux, but I'm not able to find any documentation that doesn't look like Aramaic to me.  When you say context do you mean a new type in particular?

Comment: Well if you're looking for an Aramaic speaker, I've heard Jesus was fluent :)

Yeah this is where it gets tough. I believe the type is what is intended for a process. This link may be helpful:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/chap-security-enhanced_linux-selinux_contexts